# How to tell if a window is minimized using GJS?

Tags: javascript, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

The wrappers for GJS/Gnome don't seem to expose the "minimized" property.
There is a get_maximized(), but this doesn't seem to return the information I need.

Using the JavaScript bindings for Gnome Applets, is there a way to get whether a MetaWindow is minimized?

https://developer.gnome.org/meta/stable/MetaWindow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property minimized is exposed in Gjs.

In LookingGlass ([Alt]+[F2], then "lg") try this :

```
global.screen.get_active_workspace().list_windows()[0].minimized
```

Comment: Indeed the `minimized` property's it, but this example no longer works on the current version of Gnome Shell, 3.38.3 since `global.screen` is not defined. Instead: `global.get_window_actors().map(a=>a.meta_window)[0].minimized`